# Create .pem file for Google Manage Domains

Tags: pem, authsub

I used this code

# Generate the RSA keys and certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -subj \
  '/C=US/ST=CA/L=Mountain View/CN=www.example.com' -keyout \
  myrsakey.pem -out /tmp/myrsacert.pem
```

From here:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html#Registered

Google links to this from their own ManageDomains site. I have used the code, and uploaded the pem file to Google. When I test it, it gives me this error:

SyntaxError: Missing PEM Prefix

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I've wasted several hours on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `myrsacert.pem` to Google, not `myrsakey.pem` !

The file has to contain:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

source code:

```
start = s.find("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----")
end = s.find("-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
if start == -1:
    raise SyntaxError("Missing PEM prefix")
```